# Bullets not lining up in Outlook 2007, 2010, 2013

Tags: html, email, outlook, outlook-2010, outlook-2007

I am using the following code to create bullet points:

```
<tr align="left">
    <td valign="top" width="40" style="text-align:left; line-height:26px; padding: 0px;">
    &bull;
    </td>
    <td height="20" style="text-align:left;line-height:26px;padding:0px;">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
    </td>
</tr>
```

I want it to look like this:

[image: List with correct alignment]

But it looks like this:

[image: List with wrong alignment]

Comment: Well, you put the bullet in a separate table row, so there you go.

Comment: It's in the same tr but a different td

Answer (score 0):

Check paddings and margins for 'p' and 'li'.

Comment: Forgot to select it as code. Not padding and not using `li`.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `<head>`:

```
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <style type="text/css">
    li {text-indent: -1em;}
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Try this instead for your list:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can add any extra formatting effects you like.

Good luck.

Comment: I've always been taught not to use ul and li as out outlook has issues with it. Unless I have wrongly been advised?

Comment: @NathJP My customer base is full of pesky Outlook users. I don't have many needs for bullets, but when I use them, this is what I do.